# add/remove from wishlist having trouble in handling the response data

Tags: jquery

This is my jQuery to add/remove from a wish list. I `echo` added/add to wish list and receive response.

The PHP part is fine, my problem is that the class name is the same for displaying the wish list in all products so `innerHtml` changes in every product on execution. Each product has a unique id though.

How can I change the wish list icon of only clicked div?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addingwish', function() {
  var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var email = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>";
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "actionadd.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      product_id: product_id,
      email: email
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.addingwish').html('');
      $('.addingwish').html(data);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question, you want to target the clicked element when setting the `html()` from the response of the AJAX request.

To do that store a reference to the clicked element in the event handler, using the `this` keyword, and use that when calling `html()`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addingwish', function() {
  let $el = $(this);
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "actionadd.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      product_id: $el.prop('id'),
      email: '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $el.html(data);
    }
  })
});
```

Note that you don't need to call `html('')` to clear the existing content as it's overwritten when setting the new content.

Comment: yeah ...thanks it works jst fine